# No uiautomatorviewer in android sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, uiautomatorviewer

I am using ubuntu 19.04. I want to automate some actions of an android app, I download the android studio, edit PATH, run studio.sh file, it asks to download sdk, I go with 'standard' installation. It downloads and installs, evrything fine and I successfully run avd manager and virtual device, install the app and use it. No problem with appium as well. But here comes the problem, no matter which tutorial I follow, uiautomatorviewer is all over internet as the tool to find id of the elements on active screen. But, there is NO EXECUTABLE file of uiautomatorviewer in android-sdk/tools. I search in platform-tools/, it's not there and not in bin/ as well. So I recursively searched whole directory of android studio and android sdk but there is not executable name 'uiautomaor' or 'uiautomatorviewer'. There is a uiautomatorviewer.jar file but I am unable to run it with jave -jar command. I have searched through android studio docs for some recent update but an article update on 3 march 2020 mentions uiautomatorviewer. Please help!
I've spent over 4 days trying to find uiautomatorviewer in android sdk, have reinstalled and android sdk over 4 times, have trying downloading it from official site and extracting it, tried with snap, but just couldn't find a way around.

Comment: Did you try checking the folder “$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin”?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get UiAutomatorViewer by deleting android SDK, downloading Android Studio and installing SDK using Android Studio. It installed SDK manager and some packages among which was UiAutomator.